# SqlAlchemy select with max, group_by and order_by

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have to list the last modified resources for each group, for that I can do this query:

```
model.Session.query(
    model.Resource, func.max(model.Resource.last_modified)
).group_by(model.Resource.resource_group_id).order_by(
    model.Resource.last_modified.desc())
```

But SqlAlchemy complains with:

```
ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) column "resource.id" must appear in
the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

How I can select only resource_group_id and last_modified columns?

In SQL what I want is this:

```
SELECT resource_group_id, max(last_modified) AS max_1
FROM resource GROUP BY resource_group_id ORDER BY max_1 DESC
```

Answer (score 12):

```
model.Session.query(
    model.Resource.resource_group_id, func.max(model.Resource.last_modified)
).group_by(model.Resource.resource_group_id).order_by(
    func.max(model.Resource.last_modified).desc())
```

Comment: Is the `order_by` required here? Shouldnt the `max` already be enough for correct aggregation here?

Answer (score 5):

You already got it, but I'll try to explain what's going on with the original query for future reference.

In sqlalchemy if you specified `query(model.Resource, ...)`, a model reference, it will list each column on the resource table in the generated SQL select statement, so your original query would look something like:

```
SELECT resource.resource_group_id AS resource_group_id,
       resource.extra_column1 AS extra_column1,
       resource.extra_column2 AS extra_column2,
       ...
       count(resource.resource_group_id) AS max_1
GROUP BY resource_group_id ORDER BY max_1 DESC;
```

This won't work with a GROUP BY.

A common way to avoid this is to specify what columns you want to select explicitly by adding them to the query method `.query(model.Resource.resource_group_id)`